# Can't find my app in Wear OS 3.0 Google Playstore

Tags: android, wear-os, samsung-galaxy-watch-4, android-wear-3.0

We have one of our Wear OS App which we were able to install on Android Wear 2.0 watches through sideloading / Apps on your phone. But not able to find our app in Playstore **Apps on your phone** in **Samsung Galaxy Watch 4**. I added survey permission to make it work on Samsung but that didn't work

`<uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.providers.context.permission.WRITE_USE_APP_FEATURE_SURVEY"/>`

Tried to search for an option **Install from Unknown resources** but couldn't find an option for Samsung Galaxy Watch 4. Below is the reference from Watch Active 2

[image: Image for reference]

Upgraded my app target version to 30, which also didn't work. I can see other apps but not my application on **Samsung Galaxy Watch 4**. What could be the issue?